# Specific problem on Radon measures from Folland's real analysis on $ C_0(X) $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Hello all I am trying to understand the concept of $ C_0(X) $ within the concept of Radon measures as presented in Folland's real analysis chapter 7, so far so good right until I came across problem 20 which reads as follows:
[image]

Where $ C_0(X) $ is the uniform closure of the space $ C_C(X) $ which is he space of continuous functions with compact support on X, and M(X) the (already known) vector space of complex Radon measures on X.
I have no idea as to how to solve neither a nor b. My instructor told me that these problems are challenging but solving them properly is crucial to understanding the course.
Really would appreciate help on this. Thanks

EDIT: finally solved it by help of comments

Comment: Where are you having trouble so we can have somewhere to start?

Comment: @Moya I am having trouble showing (in part b) that the dual of $ l^1 $ is isomorphic to $ l^\infty $. Thanks for the help

Comment: This directly follows from Theorem 6.15 in Folland since any measure on $X=\mathbb{N}$ must be $\sigma-$finite.